# How to Route URLS in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, filter, routes

I would like to achieve what Facebook has simply done with url mechaniscm. facebook.com/user leads to the a users profile page and facebook.com/page leads to a page. I would like to know how this routing is done with the first URL?

I have the basic idea. Filter selected tables for matches and selected the appropriate one if the record exists!! But whats the best way which will minimize load and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a framework such as [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) or [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) which already have this kind of URL routing that they handle automatically.  However, if you are talking about minimizing loads, a framework is not the way to go.

You can update your .htaccess to handle these requests and redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?request=$0
```

Then you use php to handle _REQUEST[request] however you like.